# Text to speech problem with incoming call in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

whether there is anyway to stop the TTS when a incoming call comes to my phone? via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the incoming call notification from link  http://peacemoon.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/android-listening-to-incomingoutgoing-phone-calls/

and stop the TTS as below

```
 public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (mTts != null) {
            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

where `mts` is

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,
            this  // TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
            );
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit ..Edited to include the code..So I should call on destroy when the Call state is ringing right..?

Comment: in the link I mentioned above, there is an state for the call "case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:" you need to stop the TTS in that and not on destroy.